# How to fix HTML previewer error in Intellij Idea?

Tags: html, intellij-idea, browser

I'm trying to preview some simple HTML code in Intellij (community edition). Yesterday I did it and it worked, but today when I tried to preview the same file I got a browser error:

[image: Browser Error: Unknown Error]

I'm not sure why it's doing this. I already tried changing the path to the browser, restarting Intellij, uninstalling and reinstalling Intellij, and restarting my computer. It has the same error for any browser that I try.

I've also tried previewing other HTML files in Intellij and I'm having the same issue. Does anyone have any ideas about what might be causing this or how to fix it?

Comment: Hi Rebecca, Welcome to Stack Overflow!, I recommend that you add the image as a direct image on the question instead of a third-party link. That way the question will remain useful to future readers. Thanks!

Comment: what IDEA version is it, what browser do you use for previewing? What does its configuration (in **Settings | Tools | Web Browsers**) look like? Please also share your idea.log (**Help > Show Log in ...**)

Comment: I'm using Intellij Idea 2020.3. I tried it with multiple browsers: chrome, firefox, edge, explorer etc.